# $compile does not render the html

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
streamService.create($scope.scream).then(function (response) {
                $scope.savedSuccessfully = true;

                $('.alert').delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
                var json = JSON.stringify(response.data).replace(/"/g, "'");
                var b = $compile("<stream datasource=\"" + json + "\" position=\"0\"> </stream >")($scope);


                $("#viewOne .left-panel").prepend(b);
            },
             function (err) {
                 $scope.message = err.data.message;
             });

        })
```

The variable b renders . It does not give me the rendered html. I want to get the html after passing the datasource value and prepend to an element .

Comment: What is `<stream>`? Does it work if you statically define `<stream datasource="{foo: 'bar'}">`?

Comment: [JavaScript compile() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_compile.asp) .. what is a $ beside compile?

Comment: <stream> is a custom directive

Comment: <stream datasource="{foo: 'bar'}"> does not work

Comment: can you provide working code sample? Using plnkr.co or ay other tool. It's hard to guess based on just this "It does not give me the rendered html"

Comment: When using angular, try to dispel the jQuery mindset.